How to evaluate $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2 x \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx $

Question

How to evaluate
$$
 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2 x \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx
$$

My attempt

To evaluate the integral
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2 x \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx
$$
We can use a substitution to help simplify the integral. Let’s substitute $x = 1 - u $ Then, $dx = -du$, and the limits change as follows:

When $x = 0$, $u = 1$.
When $x = 1$, $u = 0$.

Thus, the integral transforms as follows:
$$
I = \int_1^0 \frac{\ln(1 - (1-u)) \ln^2(1-u) \ln^2(1 + (1-u))}{1 - (1-u)} (-du).
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(u) \ln^2(1-u) \ln^2(2-u)}{u} \, du.
$$
I don't know the closed form of the integral; I got inspired by related integrals from the site.
Closed form
$$-\frac{4}{3} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{131 \zeta (3)^2}{16}+\frac{7}{3} \zeta (3) \ln ^3(2)-\frac{77}{24} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \ln (2)+\frac{217}{8} \zeta (5) \ln (2)+\frac{41 \pi ^6}{30240}-\frac{1}{18} \pi    ^2 \log ^4(2)-\frac{1}{144} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$$
Thanks to Mariusz Iwaniuk for the closed form.

Did you "invent" this problem ?

@ClaudeLeibovici Probably yes, because I don't know if the problem is known in the literature.

The integral $I$ is called a weight 6 logarithmic integral. You can check out this paper for solution techniques. In fact, your integral has a polylogarithmic closed form given in that same article.

Mathematica with Package: MultipleZetaValues gives: $$-\frac{4}{3} \pi ^2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{131 \zeta (3)^2}{16}+\frac{7}{3} \zeta (3) \ln ^3(2)-\frac{77}{24} \pi ^2 \zeta (3) \ln (2)+\frac{217}{8} \zeta (5) \ln (2)+\frac{41 \pi ^6}{30240}-\frac{1}{18} \pi
^2 \log ^4(2)-\frac{1}{144} \pi ^4 \log ^2(2)$$

$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2 (x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx$$

Performing $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=u$,
$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{u(1+u)} \, du$$
Using,
$$\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) = \log 2 - \log u - \log(1+u)\tag1$$
$$\log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) = \log^2(1-u) + \log^2(1+u)-2\log(1-u)\log(1+u)\tag2$$
$$\log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right) = \log^2 2 + \log^2(1+u)-2\log(2)\log(1+u)\tag3$$
Also,
$$\frac{1}{u(1+u)}=\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1}{1+u}$$
$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{u} \, du-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{1+u} \, du$$
$$I = I_1-I_2$$

Working with our first integral,
$$I_1= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{u} \, du$$
Now after multiplying $(1),(2),(3)$,
$$\log^3(2)\log^2(1-u)+\log^3(2)\log^2(1+u)-2\log^3(2)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)-\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log^2(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)-\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^2(2)\log^3(1+u)-2\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+\log(2)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+\log(2)\log^4(1+u)-2\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)-\log(u)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)-\log(u)\log^4(1+u)+2\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)-\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^5(1+u)-2\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)-2\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-2\log^2(2)\log^2(1+u)+4\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log(2)\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)+2\log(2)\log(u)\log^3(1+u)-4\log(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log(2)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)+2\log(2)\log^4(1+u)+4\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)$$
Dividing by $u$,
$$\frac{\log^3(2)\log^2(1-u)}{u}+\frac{\log^3(2)\log^2(1+u)}{u}-\frac{2\log^3(2)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log^3(1+u)}{u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{\log(2)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{\log(2)\log^4(1+u)}{u}-\frac{2\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log(u)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log(u)\log^4(1+u)}{u}+\frac{2\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u}-\frac{\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}-\frac{\log^5(1+u)}{u}-\frac{2\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)}{u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{4\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log(u)\log^3(1+u)}{u}-\frac{4\log(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log^4(1+u)}{u}+\frac{4\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u}$$
We have,
$$I_1=\log^3(2)A+\log^3(2)B-2\log^3(2)C-D-\log^2(2)E+2\log^2(2)F-\log^2(2)G-H-2\log^2(2)K+\log(2)L+\log(2)M-2\log(2)N-P-Q+2R-S-T-2W-2\log^2(2)X-2\log^2(2)Y+4\log^2(2)Z+2\log(2)\alpha+2\log(2)\beta-4\log(2)\gamma+2\log(2)\delta+2\log(2)\Omega+4\log(2)\tau$$
Where,
$$\boxed{A=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du=2\zeta(3)}$$
solution of A
$$\boxed{B=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)}$$
solution of B
$$\boxed{C=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{u} \, du=-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)}$$
solution of C
$$\boxed{D=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du=-\frac12 \zeta(4)}$$
solution of D
$$\boxed{E=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{\pi^4}{24}-4\text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)-\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln 2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2\ln^2 2}{6}-\frac{\ln^4 2}{6}}$$
solution of E
$$\boxed{F=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{u} \, du=-\frac{3 \pi^4}{160}+\frac{7\log(2)}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2 \log^2(2)}{12} +\frac{\log^4(2)}{12}\quad+ 2 \text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}$$
solution of F
$$\boxed{G=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log(1+u)}{u} \, du=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac58\zeta(4)+\frac72\ln(2)\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4(2)}$$
G was self-computed
$$\boxed{H=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(1+u)}{u} \, du=6\zeta(4)-\frac{21}{4}\ln(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{3}{2}\ln^{2}(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{4}\ln^{4}(2)-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
H was self-computed
$$\boxed{K=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=-\frac {\pi^4}{240}}$$
solution of K
$$\boxed{L=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{21}{24}\zeta(5)-\frac16\left(24\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{2}\ln^2(2)\zeta(3)+4\ln^3(2)\zeta(3)-\frac45\ln^5(2)-24\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)\right)}$$
L was self-computed
$$\boxed{M=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(1+u)}{u}du=24\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{2}\ln^{2}(2)\zeta(3)+4\ln^{3}(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{4}{5}\ln^{5}(2)-24\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
M was self-computed
$$\boxed{N=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u} \, du=-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(5)+\frac{21}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\\quad-\frac{21}8\ln^22\zeta(3)+\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac15\ln^52}$$
Solution of N
$$\boxed{P=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du=-2 \zeta(\bar5,1)+8 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+4 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log ^2(2)+8 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (2)-\frac{13 \zeta (3)^2}{16}+\frac{7}{6} \zeta (3) \log ^3(2)-\frac{221 \pi ^6}{30240}+\frac{\log ^6(2)}{9}-\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 \log ^4(2)}$$
Solution of P
$$Q=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^4(1+u)}{u} \, du$$
$$R=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u} \, du$$
$$S=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{T=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^5(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{1}{6}\ln^6(2)+\frac{8\pi^6}{63}+\sum_{n=0}^5 \binom{5}{n}\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}\left(\frac12\right)\ln^{5-n}(2)n!}$$
T was self-computed, you can refer the different closed forms from here
$$W=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)}{u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{X=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac58\zeta(4)+\frac72\ln(2)\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^4(2)}$$
Computed same as $G$
$$\boxed{Y=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{1}{4}\zeta(3)}$$
Above integral computed same as $B$
$$\boxed{Z=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)\log(1-u)}{u} \, du=-\frac {\pi^4}{240}}$$
Above integral computed same as $K$
$$\alpha=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{\beta=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^3(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{\pi^2}3\ln^32-\frac25\ln^52+\frac{\pi^2}2\zeta(3)+\frac{99}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}4\zeta(3)\ln^22\\-12\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)\ln2-12\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)}$$
Solution of the above integral
$$\boxed{\gamma=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{7\pi^2}{48}\zeta(3)-\frac{25}{16}\zeta(5)}$$
Solution of the above integral
$$\boxed{\delta=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{u} \, du=\frac{21}{24}\zeta(5)-\frac16\left(24\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{2}\ln^2(2)\zeta(3)+4\ln^3(2)\zeta(3)-\frac45\ln^5(2)-24\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)\right)}$$
Above integral computed same as $L$
$$\boxed{\Omega=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(1+u)}{u} \, du=24\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{2}\ln^{2}(2)\zeta(3)+4\ln^{3}(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{4}{5}\ln^{5}(2)-24\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}
$$
$\Omega$ was self-computed
$$\boxed{\tau=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{u} \, du=-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-6\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(5)+\frac{21}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\\quad-\frac{21}8\ln^22\zeta(3)+\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac15\ln^52}$$
Above integral is computed same as $N$
Computing $\alpha,W,Q,R,S$ can be done using one if these identities from here, this will lead you to sum of the above found integrals.

Working with our second integral,
$$I_2= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log\left(\frac{2u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+u}\right)}{1+u} \, du$$
Now after multiplying $(1),(2),(3)$,
$$\log^3(2)\log^2(1-u)+\log^3(2)\log^2(1+u)-2\log^3(2)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)-\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log^2(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)-\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^2(2)\log^3(1+u)-2\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+\log(2)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+\log(2)\log^4(1+u)-2\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)-\log(u)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)-\log(u)\log^4(1+u)+2\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)-\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-\log^5(1+u)-2\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)-2\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)-2\log^2(2)\log^2(1+u)+4\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log(2)\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)+2\log(2)\log(u)\log^3(1+u)-4\log(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)+2\log(2)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)+2\log(2)\log^4(1+u)+4\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)$$
Dividing by $1+u$,
$$\frac{\log^3(2)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}+\frac{\log^3(2)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log^3(2)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^2(2)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{\log(2)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{\log(2)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log(u)\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log(u)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}-\frac{\log^5(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}-\frac{2\log^2(2)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{4\log^2(2)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log(u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u}-\frac{4\log(2)\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u}+\frac{2\log(2)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u}+\frac{4\log(2)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u}$$
We have,
$$I_1=\log^3(2)A+\log^3(2)B-2\log^3(2)C-D-\log^2(2)E+2\log^2(2)F-\log^2(2)G-H-2\log^2(2)K+\log(2)L+\log(2)M-2\log(2)N-P-Q+2R-S-T-2W-2\log^2(2)X-2\log^2(2)Y+4\log^2(2)Z+2\log(2)\alpha+2\log(2)\beta-4\log(2)\gamma+2\log(2)\delta+2\log(2)\Omega+4\log(2)\tau$$
Where,
Please note I am out of notations to use so Ill be reusing the old ones,
$$\boxed{A=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)+\frac13\ln^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln(2)}$$
A was self-computed
$$\boxed{B=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac13 \ln^3(2)}$$
B was self-computed
$$\boxed{C=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{1+u} \, du = \frac{1}{3}\log^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\log(2)+\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}}$$
Solution to C
$$\boxed{D=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac{11}{4}\zeta(4)-\frac14\ln^42-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)}$$
Solution to D
$$\boxed{E=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=2 \, \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{7}{4} \, \zeta(3) \ln(2) - \frac{\pi^4}{45} + \frac{\ln^4(2)}{12} - \frac{1}{12} \pi^2 \ln^2(2)}
$$
E was self-computed
$$\boxed{F=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log(1+u)}{1+u} \, du= 2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\dfrac{21}{8}\zeta(3)\ln 2 - \dfrac{1}{45}\pi^4 + \dfrac{1}{12}\ln^4 2 - \dfrac{5}{24}\pi^2\ln^2 2}$$
F was self-computed
$$\boxed{G=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=-\frac{1}{4}\zeta \left(4\right)+2\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)-\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{4}\ln ^4\left(2\right)}$$
Solution to G
$$\boxed{H=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac14 \ln^4(2)}$$
H was self-computed
$$\boxed{K=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\zeta(3)\log(2)+\frac13\log^4(2)-\frac{\pi^4}{45}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\log^2(2)}$$
K was self-computed
$$\boxed{L=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=-4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+4\zeta(3)\log^2(2)-\frac{2\pi^2}9 \log^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{20}\log2+\frac7{30}\log^5(2)+ \frac{63}8\zeta(5) }$$
Solution to above integral
$$\boxed{M=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac15 \ln^5(2)}$$
M was self-computed
$$\boxed{N=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=6\zeta(5)-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{15}\ln(2)+3\ln^2(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln^3(2)+\frac14 \ln^5(2)}$$
Solution to N
$$P=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^2(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{Q=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=24\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{8}{315}\pi^6-\frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln^4(2)+24\ln(2)\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+12\ln^2(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln^3(2)+\frac13\ln^6(2)}$$
Q was self-computed
$$R=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{S=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du=-12 \text{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-12 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \ln (2)+6 \zeta^2 (3)+8 \zeta (3) \ln ^3(2)-12 \zeta(2) \zeta (3) \ln (2)+36 \zeta (5) \ln (2)-9\zeta(6)+\frac{1}{4}\ln ^6(2)-2\zeta(2) \ln ^4(2)-\frac{27}{2} \zeta(4) \ln ^2(2)+12  \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^52^n}}$$
S was self-computed, Also no closed form for that sum
$$\boxed{T=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^5(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac16 \ln^6(2)}$$
T was self-computed
$$\boxed{W=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^4(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=24\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{8}{315}\pi^6+24\ln(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{2}{15}\pi^4\ln^2(2)+4\ln^3(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln^4(2)+\frac15\ln^5(2)}$$
Solution to W
$$\boxed{X=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du= 2 \zeta (3) \log (2)-\frac{\pi ^4}{360}+\frac{\log ^4(2)}{4}-\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log ^2(2)}$$
Solution to X
$$\boxed{Y=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac13 \ln^3(2)}$$
Y was self-computed
$$\boxed{Z=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+u)\log(1-u)}{1+u} \, du=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\zeta(3)\log(2)+\frac13\log^4(2)-\frac{\pi^4}{45}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\log^2(2)}$$
Z was self-computed
$$\alpha=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1+u)\log^2(1-u)}{1+u} \, du$$
$$\boxed{\beta=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=6 \, \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \ln(2) - 6 \, \zeta(5) + \frac{21}{8} \, \zeta(3) \ln^2(2) + \frac{\ln^5(2)}{5} - \frac{1}{6} \pi^2 \ln^3(2)}$$
$\beta$ was self-computed

$$\gamma=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(u)\log(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du$$
You can try the following for $a=1,b=1,c=2$,
$$\sin \pi (b-a) \int_0^1 x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1+x)^{-a} dx = \sin \pi (c-a) \int_0^1 x^{a-c} \left[ (1-x)^{c-a-1}(1+x)^{-b} - 1 \right] dx - \sin \pi (b-a) \frac{\Gamma(c-b)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)} \int_0^1 x^{b-c} \left[ (1-x)^{c-a-1}(1+x)^{-b} - 1 \right] dx + \frac{\sin \pi (c-a)}{a-c+1} - \frac{\pi \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(2-c+b)\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c-a)}$$
You will have to perform the below,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a^m \partial b^n \partial c^r}$$
Picking appropriate $m,n,r$

$$\boxed{\delta=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1-u)\log^2(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=-4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+4\zeta(3)\log^2(2)-\frac{2\pi^2}9 \log^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{20}\log2+\frac7{30}\log^5(2)+ \frac{63}8\zeta(5) }$$
Computed same as $L$
$$\boxed{\Omega=\int_0^1 \frac{\log^4(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=\frac15\ln^5(2)}$$
$\Omega$ was self-computed
$$\boxed{\tau=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-u)\log^3(1+u)}{1+u} \, du=6\zeta(5)-6\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{15}\ln(2)+3\ln^2(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln^3(2)+\frac14 \ln^5(2)}$$
Solution to above integral

All the above integrals are known and trivial, derived from the beta
function, Not to mention all these integrals are documented in text
and on this site as well
$$\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}\,dt=\beta(a,b)$$
$$\int_{-1}^1(1-t)^{a-1}(1+t)^{b-1}\,dt=2^{a+b-1}\beta(a,b)$$


Another approach may go this way,
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)  \ln^2(1+x)\ln^2 x}{1-x} \, dx$$
Using the Identity,
$$ab^2=\frac{1}{6}(a+b)^3+\frac{1}{6}(a-b)^3-\frac{1}{3}a^3$$
Where,
$$a=\ln(1-x)\,||||\,  b=\ln(1+x)$$
$$\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)=\frac{1}{6}(\ln(1-x)+\ln(1+x))^3+\frac{1}{6}(\ln(1-x)-\ln(1+x))^3-\frac{1}{3}(\ln(1-x))^3$$
$$\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)=\frac{1}{6}\ln^3(1-x^2)+\frac{1}{6}\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3(1-x)$$
$$\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)\ln^2 x=\frac{1}{6}\ln^3(1-x^2)\ln^2 x+\frac{1}{6}\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^2 x-\frac{1}{3}\ln^3(1-x)\ln^2 x$$
$$\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{6}\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)\ln^2 x}{1-x}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^2 x}{1-x}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln^2 x}{1-x}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)\ln^2 (x)}{1-x}\,dx+\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln^2(x)}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln^2 (x)}{1-x}\,dx$$
You can then refer here and here and here for further.

+1) This is the kind of answer that I immediately bookmark. The links you've compiled to related integrals seem very handy to have in one place :)

@DavidH thank you sir, there’s a lot more integrals in there to complete with proof/references, hopefully whenever I’m free I’ll keep editing

Let's consider the general case
$$I(a,n)= \int_{0}^{1}x^a\ln^n (x)\frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx;\,n=0,1... $$
All we need is the following expansion:
$$\ln^2(1-x)=2\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{H_{m-1}}{m}x^m$$
where
$$H_{m}=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}$$
Now differentiate the expansion with respect to $x$
$$\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}=-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}H_{m}x^m$$
In the original expansion, we take $-x$ instead of $x$
$$\ln^2(1+x)=2\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}(-1)^m\frac{H_{m-1}}{m}x^m$$
Now we form the product
$$x^a\frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x}$$
and integrate
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^a\frac{\ln(1-x) \ln^2(1+x)}{1-x} \, dx = $$
$$=-2\sum_{m=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^mf(m)}{m+1+a}$$
where
$$f(m)=\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(-1)^i\frac{H_{i}H_{m-1-i}}{m-i}$$
Finally, we differentiate the obtained result by $a$ $n$ times and get the final result:
$$I(a,n)=-2(-1)^nn!\sum_{m=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^mf(m)}{(m+1+a)^{n+1}}$$
We get the integral given in the original post here by taking $a=0$ and $n=2$
